# Leaflet Snap - Cannot snap when drawing using Leaflet Draw

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, draw, haskell-snap-framework

I'm quite new in js and leaflet and I need your help. I use leaflet draw for drawing and editing polygons on a map and I need to be able to snap to other polygons while drawing. I used plugin Leaflet Snap for this and it works - unfortunately only when the polygon is already in map so it only works for editing. I can't seem to find solution for this anywhere on the internet. It is working in this demo - http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.Snap/. BUT - it only works when you initialize drawControl like this `var map = L.map('map', {drawControl: true})`

The problem is, I need to create toolbar with `L.Control.Draw` because I only need to draw polygon and marker and not all the other stuff:

```
let drawControlFull = new L.Control.Draw({
                    edit: {
                        featureGroup: this.newLayer
                    },
                    draw: {
                        polyline: false,
                        circle: false,
                        rectangle: false,
                        circlemarker: false,
                        polygon: {
                            guideLayers: [this.floorPolygons],
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Since I'm building large Vue app I can only provide easy example https://jsfiddle.net/leanna_b/kwp2uh7a/.
Any ideas where the problem might be? Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Try out this library: https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman

Comment: Thanks I know about this library, but really need to figure this out with Leaflet Draw.